# TagCloud-reactJS won't stop making duplicate tag clouds

Tags: css, reactjs, tag-cloud

So I'm trying to make a mobile friendly tag cloud for my portfolio site, only problem is my tag cloud keeps repeating itself and I can't for the likes of me figure out how to fix it. I'm using TagCloud-reactJS Example here: https://github.com/sairamkiran9/TagCloud-reactJS

here's what it looks like on a mobile phone: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rFdt0.png

here's the code:

index.js

```html
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import TagCloud from 'TagCloud';
import AnimatedLetters from '../AnimatedLetters';
import './index.scss'
import Loader from 'react-loaders';
import TagsCanvas from 'react-tags-canvas'

const container = '.tagCloud';
const texts = [
  'React.js', 'Python', 'JavaScript',
  'CSS3', 'Java', 'Jquery',
  'HTML5', 'C#', 'Ajax', 'ASP.NET',
  'SQL Server 2019', 'Visual Studio 2019',
  'Team Foundation Server (GIT)',
  'Google Maps API', 'SendGrid', 'Telerik UI', 'Blazor', 'Android Studio'
];

const options = {
  radius: 400,
  // animation speed
  // slow, normal, fast
  maxSpeed: 'fast',
  initSpeed: 'fast',
  // 0 = top
  // 90 = left
  // 135 = right-bottom
  direction: 135,
  // interact with cursor move on mouse out
  keep: true
};

const Skills = () => {

   useEffect(() => {
     TagCloud(container, texts, options);
   })

   useEffect(() => {
     setTimeout(() => {
     return TagCloud(container, texts, options)
    }, 4000)
  }, [])

  
  const [letterClass, setLetterClass] = useState('text-animate')

  useEffect(() => {
     setTimeout(() => {
     return setLetterClass('text-animate-hover')
    }, 3000)
  }, [])

 
  return (

    

    <div  className='container skills-page'>
        <div className="text-zone">
          <h1>
            <AnimatedLetters
              letterClass={letterClass}
              strArray={['S', 'k', 'i', 'l', 'l', 's']}
              idx={15}
            />
          </h1>
          <p>
            Expert in a wide variety of coding languages such as HTML5, CSS3, Javascript, Jquery, React, Bootstrap, Git, Java, Python, C#, SQL, etc.
          </p>
          <p float="left">
             I specialize in building aesthetic looking websites on the front end, as well as making my back end code extremely efficient with the least amount of overhead possible. I try my best to ensure
             each page I build has a mobile friendly design and that my code is as easy to understand and as reusable as it can possibly be. 
          </p>
          <p>
            Feel free to visit my <a href='https://github.com/EricTilton'>Github</a> page for some of my work.
          </p>
          
        </div>
      
         <div  className='cloudContainer'> 

        <span id="root" className="tagCloud"/>
       
        </div> 

        <div className='black'> 
        
       
        </div> 

        <Loader type="ball-grid-pulse" />
    </div>
  )
}


export default Skills
```

index.scss

```html
.container.skills-page {

a {
  color: #00e1ff
  }


body{
    margin-top: 3px;
    padding: 1px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
   
  }
  h1 {
    //text-align: left;
    //margin-bottom: 200px;
  }

  p {
    //margin-bottom: 200px;
  }

  .text-zone{
    margin-bottom: 400px;
  }


  .main {
    justify-content: center;
  }


  .tagcloud {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    right: auto;
    bottom: 6000px;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;  
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 650;
    margin-left: 50%;
    mask-repeat: no-repeat;
    
  }
  .tagcloud--item:hover {
    color: #00e1ff 
    
  }

  

 
}

  @media screen and (max-width: 1200px)  {

    .cloudContainer{
      position: relative;
      transform: scale(0.5) translate(-100%, -100%);
      top: 800px;
      right: 25px;
      
    }

    .tagCloud {
    position: relative;
    top: auto;
    bottom: 500px;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;  
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 650;
    margin-right:  200%;
    mask-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transform: scale(0.5) translate(-100%, -100%);
   

    }

    h1 {
      font-size: 53px;
      font-family: 'Coolvetica';
      color: #00e1ff;
      font-weight: 400;
      margin-top: 0;
      position: relative;
      margin-bottom: 40px;
      left: -10px;

      &:before {
        content: '<h1>';
        font-family: 'La Belle Aurore', cursive;
        color: #00e1ff;
        font-size: 18px;
        position: absolute;
        margin-top: -10px;
        left: -10px;
        opacity: 0.6;
        line-height: 18px;
      }

      &:after {
        content: '<h1/>';
        font-family: 'La Belle Aurore', cursive;
        color: #00e1ff;
        font-size: 18px;
        line-height: 18px;
        position: absolute;
        left: -30px;
        bottom: -20px;
        margin-left: 20px;
        opacity: 0.6;
      }
    }

    .container.skills-page {
      
      
    }

    .content{
      position: center;
      float: center;
     
      
    }  

 
  }
```

Any help would be appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are calling TagCloud in two separate useEffect hooks.

Comment: I took out the second useEffect hook and tried with the first one. Still have the same problem.